# Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php

I have written a small shipping in extension for my opencart it works fine but when i haven't set a region/state for an address i get the below error

> **Warning**: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   **/home/51/html/k/catalog/controller/fastshipping/shipping.php** on
>   line **289**

but once the field is set it works great. Since my form is jquery the shipping form doesn't loads coz of that warning.

below is the code

```
if (isset($defaultshippingmethod['quote'][key($defaultshippingmethod['quote'])]['code'])) 
{
    $this->data['code'] = $defaultshippingmethod['quote'][key($defaultshippingmethod['quote'])]['code'];
} 
else {
    $this->data['code'] = '';
}
```

can someone please tell me how can fix that? (not just disable php warning)

Comment: The message is telling you that this variable `$defaultshippingmethod['quote']` is not set. You'll need to fix that yourself since there's no code here that suggests when it should be set.

Answer (score 3):

replace the `if` to :

```
if (isset($defaultshippingmethod['quote']) && 
 isset($defaultshippingmethod['quote'][key($defaultshippingmethod['quote'])]['code']))
```

the error is because there no entry in the array

```
$defaultshippingmethod['quote']
```